# Customise Django makemigrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am trying to create a management command which will create two migrations, one for adding models, fields etc, and the other for deleting, so that I can apply one of the migrations before deploying the app and the other after deployment has been on all the servers.

Is there any simple way of achieving this without human intervention?

Comment: You can `makemigrations` to create a file and then customise it as needed…!? Or just make a new migrations file by hand entirely.

Comment: I am trying to automate this process.

Comment: I have an odd idea, this may be not the proper way. Write a custom `django-admin` command which will invoke a function that ultimately refers to a shell script, which would do, remove your current migration files form a app and then make the migration.
To write a admin-command follow: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/
For remove migrations:
`find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete`
`find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete`

Answer (score 0):

You could import the migration file, iterate over `Migration.operations` and split it into two files according to your requirements. You will also have to check if there any dependencies on that migration and adjust them.

This would still be a hack and most likely doesn't cover all the edge cases. A proper solution would probably involve rewriting large chunks `django.db.migrations`.